# How to insert array into specific index of array?

Tags: javascript

I have tried the following but they don't work.
I want a result like `[[[arr1],[arr2],[arr3]],[[arr4],[arr5],[arr6]]]`.

```
array3[counter].push(array2[e+f]);
//Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'push' of undefined 

array3.splice(counter,0,array2[e+f]);
//[Array[2], Array[3], Array[4], Array[4], Array[2], Array[3]]
```

Here is my source code if it helps:
http://jsfiddle.net/yUXPz/

Comment: `array3[counter]` is the value at index counter, not an array - hence you can't call `.push` on it.

Comment: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'push' of undefined" -> array3[counter] = undefined -> no value at counter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're trying to add an array to array3 at the specified counter location then use this:

```
            array3[counter] = [];
            array3[counter].push(array2[e+f]);
```

Here is the output I got:

```
[
  [
    [
      7,
      8,
      9
    ]
  ],
  [
    [
      3,
      3,
      3,
      4
    ]
  ]
]
```

Is that what you're looking to get?

Comment: I needed the array to look like this `[[[arr1],[arr2],[arr3]],[[arr4],[arr5],[arr6]]]` i.e. 3 arrays in every array, because my code was just to help me solve this HackerRank problem: https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/two-arrays., and I needed that array structure for my algorithm.